# Minimize $\left(a+\frac1a\right)\left(a+\frac1b\right)$+$\left(b+\frac1b\right)\left(b+\frac1c\right)$+$\left(c+\frac1c\right)\left(c+\frac1a\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, contest-math

Question: Minimize $\left(a+\frac1a\right)\left(a+\frac1b\right)+\left(b+\frac1b\right)\left(b+\frac1c\right)+\left(c+\frac1c\right)\left(c+\frac1a\right)$
when $a+b=c+2$ and $a,b,c>0$.

I tried to replace $c$ with $a+b-2$ but it didn't bring me anywhere..

Comment: If it helps, I put this into a numerical optimizer and got $a=8/5,b=23/15,c=17/15$, which means there's no symmetry in the solution.

Comment: Ah yes, I input the function incorrectly on my end (a * instead of a +).

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut This was one of high school math contest problems.

Comment: @KayK. What contest?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut It's not a contest inside US. It's from one of far east countries. I don't know its exact name. My colleague in that country asked me.

Comment: You are doing the right thing, but just have to take the derivative of the resulting function in regards to $a$ and then in regards to $b$. Should this help?

Comment: Is it solvable by AM-GM inequality? I don't know neither. But I saw a question similar before.

Comment: Maybe it means $a+b+c=2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$f(a,b,c):=\left(a+\frac1a\right)\left(a+\frac1b\right)+\left(b+\frac1b\right)\left(b+\frac1c\right)+\left(c+\frac1c\right)\left(c+\frac1a\right)$$
$$f(a,b,c)=\begin{cases}
a,b,c>0\\
a+b=c+2
\end{cases}$$
[Wolfram's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%5B%7B(1%2Fa+%2B+a)+(a+%2B+1%2Fb)+%2B+(1%2Fb+%2B+b)+(b+%2B+1%2Fc)+%2B+(1%2Fa+%2B+c)+(1%2Fc+%2B++++++++c),+a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+c+%2B+2,+a+%3E+0,+b+%3E+0,+c+%3E+0%7D,+%7Ba,+b,+c%7D%5D) answer is ${a\rightarrow1.42163, b \rightarrow 1.36931, c \rightarrow 0.790944}$ with $f(a,b,c)=13.1738$.

This is actually moot, but my answer, if we disregard the second restriction (i.e. $a+b=c+2$), would be $f(a,b,c)=12$ with $a,b,c=1$.

We take the partial derivatives of $f$ w.r.t $a,b,c$ and solve the system of equations. Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=0, \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=0, \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=0,
\end{align}$$
And thus we solve:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}&=-\frac{1}{a^2 b}-\frac{c}{a^2}-\frac{1}{a^2 c}+2 a+\frac{1}{b}=0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}&=-\frac{a}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a b^2}-\frac{1}{b^2 c}+2 b+\frac{1}{c}=0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}&=-\frac{1}{a c^2}+\frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{c^2}-\frac{1}{b c^2}+2 c=0,
\end{align}$$
Which gives us a solution over $\mathbb{R}$ : $a,b,c=\begin{cases}1\\-1\end{cases}$, and given the first restriction, $a,b,c=1$

It puzzles me that if we take the second restriction into account, $\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=0, \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=0, \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=0,
\end{align}$ has $\emptyset$ as a solution.